# How to get an element from an iframe from another domain in JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I need to get the value of the last column from the [following url](https://atlas.brabant.nl/arcgis/services/fauna/MapServer/WMSServer?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&QUERY_LAYERS=0&LAYERS=0&INFO_FORMAT=text%2Fhtml&I=50&J=50&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&STYLES=&WIDTH=101&HEIGHT=101&BBOX=561233.7279644652%2C6710614.5767957475%2C576674.0076780707%2C6726054.856509354), so that I can use that for input for another url.

This url is being displayed in an iframe, with it's source coming from another domain (the domain in the url above).

The part of my function containing this code is currently looking like this:

```
if (url) {
    document.getElementById('techtable').innerHTML =
      '<iframe id="myframe" src="' + url + '"></iframe>';
    overlay.setPosition(coordinates);
    var iframe = document.getElementById("myframe");
    console.log(iframe);
    var docu = iframe.contentDocument;
    console.log(docu);
    var elmnt = docu.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
    console.log(elmnt);
    var idtext = $('elmnt tbody tr:first td:last').text();
    console.log(idtext);
}
```

The console.log's can be seen in this screen capture:
[image: Console.log's]

What happens is that the second console.log is showing the document from the iframe, but it is only returning an empty head and body tag, while these tags are filled in the first log. The problem is that I cannot find a reason why this is occurring. It might be the fact that the source is from another domain, although I do not see any errors in the console, or that my function/syntax is wrong.

So, if it's possible, how do I get the value of the last column of the table in the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

Two issues merit investigation:

1. The posted code is synchronous - it attempts to log the content of the `iframe` element before giving it a chance to load content across the net from the url set in its `src` attribute.

   Possibly, and perhaps even likely, the *second* log which was made synchronously could be showing the document of an "about:blank" document object initially loaded in the iframe element.

   Given that objects logged on the console tend to be live, the *first* log entry may have been updated after iframe content was loaded - or the log entry in the screen shot was expanded after loading was complete.
2. Access to documents from different domains my be blocked for security reasons. This does not necessarily mean `console.log` is blocked from showing the content, it means access to the content from JavaScript may be impossible.

**How to debug**

a) Access iframe content from within load event listeners registered on the iframe element.

b) test using a url from the same domain. If that works but access fails for documents from a different domain then you may need to investigate CORS further. Discussing hypotheticals here is a little early.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Result of debug a): I've put the code in a function, while calling onload="myfunction()" on the iframe element. This resulted in a CORS error. Result of debug b): I've tried the same function with another localhost website instead of the url from another domain, which did work. So my best guess is the fact that is has something to do cross domain scripting.

Comment: Agreed. I proceeded further and successfully loaded the dutch site in an iframe (so I could see the table).  After loading, however,  the `iframeElement.contentDocument` was null -meaning access blocked by security. Trying a cross domain Ajax request for the same url resulted in an error stating that "CORS preflight channel did not succeed". Sorry I can't help further.